# Как сделать что бы input принимал только цифры и была маска на js (банковская карта)

Tags: javascript, html, валидация, mask, keypress

на счет маски попробовал сделать так

```
HTML
<input type="number" class="card-number">
```

```
JS
//Карточка
  let input_card = document.querySelector('.card-number');
  let count_card = 0;
  input_card.addEventListener('keypress', function() {
    if (count_card == 4) {
      count_card = 0;
      this.value += ' ';
    }
    count_card++;
  });
```

При вводе 4 символов поле снова пустое. Возможно нельзя к типу number добавлять пробел.

Answer (score 0):

Да. Там проблема в том, что это не текстовый инпут. Оставь его тип текстовым, а перед отправкой, если сервер ждёт именно числовой тип, просто убери все пробелы и кастани к number. Ну и надо не забыть провалидировать так же перед отправкой, чтобы строка не содержала ничего кроме цифр.

```js
  let input_card = document.querySelector('.card-number');
  let count_card = 0;
  input_card.addEventListener('keypress', function() {
    if (count_card == 4) {
      count_card = 0;
      this.value += ' ';
    }
    count_card++;
  });
```

```html
<input type="text" class="card-number">
```